# Problem Parsing SVG files After http to https migration

Tags: svg, https, embed

I've just converted https://www.donbur.co.uk/ to https and am going through bug fixes.

One bug is that svgs no longer parse.  I'm getting the "This XML does not appear to have any style information associated with it." line.

e.g. https://www.donbur.co.uk/gb-en/css/img/menu-icon-pmr.svg

I've read in some places it's down to http calls but I've checked and all calls are https.  I even have a RewriteRule to convert all http requests to https.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not change the namespaces. The following is correct.

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

These are not URLs, they just look like URLs.

Comment: .Interesting.  I did a site-wide find/replace.  I didn't anticipate that it would change the xml in svg files.  Thanks